# Using Html form passing parameter to java file

Tags: java, html, servlets

Passing Parameter to the Java file using Html form I couldn't run in my Tomcat server.
Who can describe this example step by step? where shall I put .html file and where .java and . class files. I am attaching html and java file. The compiled file with .class extension I have already done! Thank you in advance!

```
<html>

<head>
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Login</h2>
<p>Please enter your username and password</p>
<form method="GET" action="/htmlform/LoginServlet">
  <p> Username  <input type="text" name="username" size="20"></p>
  <p> Password  <input type="text" name="password" size="20"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"></p>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

</body>

</html>
```

and this is my LoginServlet.java file:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                                   throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String name = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("Thanks  Mr." + "  " + name + "  " + "for visiting roseindia<br>" );
    out.println("Now you can see your password : " + "  " + pass + "<br>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML file has to go in public webcontent and the class file has to go in `/WEB-INF/classes` in the right folder structure which conforms the class' `package` declaration. Also don't forget to declare the servlet in `/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

As to the HTML form, you need to realize that a leading slash `/` in the URL will bring you to domain root. So effectively your form submits to http://localhost:8080/htmlform/LoginServlet. You need to ensure that the webapp context path is indeed named `/htmlform` and that the Servlet is in `web.xml` been mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/LoginServlet`.

#### See also:

- [About Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - Contains a Hello World example and several useful tutorial/resource links.

---

Unrelated to the problem, Roseindia.net is considered the worst learning/example source. Relatively a lot of snippets over there are cluttered by bad practices. I'd suggest to ignore that list as long as you're new.

Comment: Thank You for the fast reply! Actually I have put .java file in /WEB-INF/classes, and also set the web.xml . I am sorry, but what did you mean, when said "public webcontent"??

Comment: The `.class` file, not the `.java` file. The public webcontent is there where your `/WEB-INF` folder is been placed. Did you click and follow the "Abous Servlets" link anyway?

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going to try now! and thank you about roseindia :)

Comment: I followed About Servlets link. I am having some problem there. I did all as described, but exception report was shown in browser. I set web.xml, put .jsp file in webapps\contextname\WEB-INF, put the HelloServlet.class in classes/com/example folder. web.xml is also in WEB-INFO folder. And finally in browser i paste the path http://localhost:8080/contextname/hello

Comment: What exception exactly did you get? Just a "Resource not found"?

Comment: The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: OK, an exception has been thrown. Read the server logs, the stacktrace is there. Interpret it and fix the root cause of the problem accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I fully understand the question but it seems to be asking where to put java code and html files for tomcat to use them.  These resources are typically packaged together into a .war file and deployed into tomcat.

Comment: The question wasn't asked very good, sorry for my english! I have html and java files, I have set my web.xml. Now I running my Tomcat server,but don't know how can I send data from html to java. LoginServlet.java and LoginServlet.class are in 'classes' folder. web.xml is in WEB-INF folder. But where to put html file,? in which folder? and also the problem is that i can't manage the paths, I mean for example in html file arethe string like this : "action="/htmlform/LoginServlet", from where does this path's start begin? from htmlform folder or ...?

Comment: Typically, yes. Necessary, no.

Comment: I can't find out the problem. After clicking on submit button, page goes to file://localhost/LoginServlet?username=sdhsdghgh&password=ghghgghgh&B1=Submit, and couldn't open the file. What am I doing wrong? help me to find out my problem please

Comment: I have noticed this: if I am clicking on Submit button, the url is written like file://localhost/htmlform/LoginServlet?username=Vardges&password=Begoy&B1=Submit,
 but if I am correcting the url path from the browser like http://localhost:8080/htmlform/LoginServlet?username=Vardges&password=Begoyan&B1=Submit, it is working. 
Can anybody explain how and from where can I set the url path before clickin on submit button. Thank you in advance!